# Cant run standalone.bat file

Tags: java, batch-file, ubuntu, jakarta-ee, jboss

I am trying to run java EE application on server (using wild fly which is the JBoss community edition). I have built a .war file (named `Project_war.war` which I have located in `wildfly/standalone/deployments`) and now I just go to `wildfly/bin` and run `./standalone.bat` but it gives the following error:

```
./standalone.bat: line 1: @echo: command not found 
./standalone.bat: line 2: rem: command not found 
./standalone.bat: line 3: rem: command not found 
./standalone.bat: line 4: rem: command not found
./standalone.bat: line 5: $'\r': command not found 
./standalone.bat: line 6: rem: command not found 
./standalone.bat: line 7: rem: command not found 
./standalone.bat: line 8: rem: command not found
./standalone.bat: line 9: $'\r': command not found 
./standalone.bat: line 10: @if: command not found 
./standalone.bat: line 11: $'setlocal\r': command not found 
./standalone.bat: line 12: $'\r': command not found 
./standalone.bat: line 13: rem: command not found
./standalone.bat: line 16: rem: command not found 
./standalone.bat: line 18: $'\r': command not found 
./standalone.bat: line 19: $'\r': command not found 
./standalone.bat: line 20: syntax error near unexpected token `(' '
./standalone.bat: line 20: `if NOT "x%DEBUG%" == "x" (
```

Any suggestions?
P.S. I am using ubuntu

Comment: Are you using Windows?

Comment: @Ivan no, Ubuntu.

Comment: I do not know about .war files but I believe your issue is that the dos PATH variable has not been set correctly (or maybe at all).

Comment: Ubuntu is **Linux**, so why are you trying to run a **Windows** .bat file? On Linux, you need to run shell scripts, most likely Bash scripts.

Comment: My suggestion is if you really want help with running a Windows batch file, to post its content, _correctly formatted using the`{}` button_, by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51369130/edit). Of course if you're not running Windows, then my suggestion is that you shouldn't be running a Windows batch file.

Comment: @Andreas how can I run wildfly on ubuntu ?

Comment: There is a `standalone.sh` file for Linux. `standalone.bat` is specifically for Windows. See the **documentation**, i.e. the [Getting Started with WildFly 8](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Getting+Started+Guide#GettingStartedGuide-StartingWildFly8) guide.

Comment: @Andreas is right; it’s just `standalone.sh` on Linux.

Comment: @Andreas oh, my bad. New to ubuntu as well. It worked. Make an answer please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you run the standalone.bat file on Ubuntu. Try running the corresponding `.sh` file. That should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Hope you are inside bin directory ! Just run this command :)

```
> sh standalone.sh
```

---

**BONUS:**

Now, just in case still it's not running :

1. Goto back (`cd ..`) => now enter standalone folder (`cd standalone`)
2. Go inside configuration folder (`cd configuration`)
3. Here you will see a standalone.xml file
4. Open this file using some editor
5. Search for "offset" in this file
6. Replace 0 with 9 here:

   `port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:9}">`
7. Now again run the sh standalone.sh command after going back to bin folder.

---

Try

```
http://localhost:8089
```

And upvote if that runs  : )